# Пауза перед загрузкой CSS

Tags: apache, html, css

Сегодня обнаружил удивительную вещь. Сайт, который должен летать (работает на localhost), немного притормаживает.

Кинулся смотреть, в чем дело. Оказалось, что после загрузки html-документа браузер где-то 50-70 мс ждет с моря погоды. Даже не пытаясь загрузить CSS. Ну а потом грузит.

[image: Imgur]

Чем это вызвано? К примеру, на этом сайте все нормально.

Это норма:

[image: Imgur]

Comment: @brizz да чем угодно, сеть была занята, html еще не распарсился, браузер подчищал свои внутренние данные, проблемы синхронизации, да что угодно. Ваш сайт не говорит браузеру "так, а теперь подожди лишних миллисекунд сто", не волнуйтесь. Вы что, визуально заметили эти 50 мс?

Comment: Да, я замечаю:) Меня удивляет, что тут дело не в сети. Я проверял сотни раз, подгружая документ, в котором только один тег (загрузка стилей). Все равно есть простой 50-70 мс. Чудеса...=)

Comment: У вас, возможно, открыт инспектор и стоит вот эта (http://SSMaker.ru/93c450ba/) галочка. Из-за неё у меня такое бывало.

Comment: Нет такого...